# Powerpoint SaveAs textbox form entry

Tags: vba, forms, powerpoint, save-as

Hello I have the following code written below to automatically send an email confirming that the user has filled out a form. Currently I have a powerpoint with one submit button which sends an automatic email. I also have a textbox named serial number where the user enters the part serial number.

I want to be able to send a copy of the filled out powerpoint form and have it named after the serial number. I am struggling to be able to save the textbox information as a variable. Does anyone know how to make the below functional. I apologize as I am fairly new to VBA.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Powerpoint      As Presentation
Dim SerialNumtext   As String
Dim FinalName       As String

SerialNumtext = ActivePresentation.SelectContentControlsByTitle("SerialNumber")(1).Range.Text
FinalName = "Part Number" & SerialNumtext

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Powerpoint = ActivePresentation
Powerpoint.Save


With EmailItem
.Subject = "SUBJECT LINE"
.Body = "BODY MESSAGE" & vbCrLf & _
"SECOND LINE BODY MESSAGE" & vbCrLf & _
"THIRD LINE BODY MESSAGE"
.To = "enduseremail"
.Importance = olImportanceNormal
'send the email with the powerpoint named after the serial number
.Attachments.Add Powerpoint.FinalName
.Send
 End With

 Set Powerpoint = Nothing
 Set OL = Nothing
 Set EmailItem = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerpoint doesn't have a SelectContentControlsByTitle method; instead, you'd access the control and its text like:

```
SerialNumtext = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("SerialNumber").OLEFormat.Object.Text
```

This assumes the control is on Slide 1.

If you'd rather not make that assumption but can assume that the Submit button and text box are on the same slide:

```
SerialNumText = Me.Shapes("SerialNumber").OLEFormat.Object.Text
```

Me in this case returns a reference to the slide object that contains the control.